# Navigation bar won't go fixed when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to make a navigation bar that when you scroll down it goes to the top and the `position` is `fixed`. But no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/S99FB/1/

I need help.

Comment: Seems to be working, but it is pushed off to the side because your width on the navbar is set to 100%.

Comment: seems to be working for me. It does apply the class `nav-bar fixed`.. what browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome browser

Comment: it already worked but my problem is it only goes up when my scroll bar is already at the bottom http://jsfiddle.net/S99FB/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the div is in the position where window-scrolltop position less div-offset are = 0, apply the class. This class will make the div have position fixed and top value 0. When the substraction is negative then remove the class so the div has its normal position.

http://jsfiddle.net/FL8gq/

```
var nav_bar = $('#nav_bar'),// cache this
    top = nav_bar.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() - top) > 0 && !nav_bar.hasClass('navbar-fixed')) {
        nav_bar.addClass('navbar-fixed');
    } else if (($(window).scrollTop() - top) < 0 && nav_bar.hasClass('navbar-fixed')) {
        nav_bar.removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the header tag css also.

```
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing `width: 100%;` from `navbar-fixed` CSS

Comment: thanks but it wasn't smooth when it goes to top like this example http://crshd.github.io/